# Emacs windmove key in Mac

Tags: macos, emacs

I set Alt as the windmove key to switch between frames in Emacs under Mac.

```
(windmove-default-keybindings 'meta)
```

This works fine for the GUI version Emacs (the one with the widgets and other windows decorations), but not if I start emacs with `emacs -nw` from a Mac Terminal.app. For example, if I split window first with `C-x 2`, and press `Alt + <Down>`, then Emacs reports

```
 ESC + <Down> is undefined.
```

Can anyone help?

Emacs version is 24.4 installed from brew install.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the easiest way is to just install [iterm2](http://iterm2.com/). And in the Preferences > Profiles tab. Select your profile on the left, and then open the Keyd tab and set the option key to `+ESC`.

Then in your emacs setup set the key manually,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <down>") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <left>") 'windmove-left)
```

I suggest you to use `iterm2` since it's a better terminal. But in case you want to use terminal.app don't forget to check the `Use option as meta key` in Preferences > Settings > Keyboard, it works to some extend with the default emacs.

Comment: I've added this into .emacs file, and it is not working.

Comment: @K.Chen Just updated my answer. Try the second code.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is true for Ubuntu when I use `terminator` as a terminal.

You can work around this problem by using the `win-switch` package which works fine in every case for me. Here you have a simple configuration that you can put in your init file (.e.g.: `.emacs`):

```lisp
;; install win-switch package using package manager
(if (package-installed-p 'win-switch)
    nil
  (package-install 'win-switch))

;; my favourite quick keybindings
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<left>")  'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>")    'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>")  'windmove-down)
```

The `win-switch` package has many other powerful utilities which are further detailed in the commentary part of the code.